Tabs bar for expo app using expo-router too far away from bottom screen
i am trying to get started with react-native and i want to create a tab bottom bar for some 'pages' i want ot have in the app,
i saw some videos and figured out it should be implemented as a Stack.Screen compenent for allowing other files to be routed and not all the files to have in the tab bar,
for some reason, the Tab bar is not tight to the bottom of my screen, it like adding too big of a gap to the bottom which i cant get it and does not understand why its doing that,
if someone can help me i would be greatful

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
